# How to fix validate plug-ins Missing Constraint: errors when moving from Eclipse Mars2 to Neon and changing target framework back to 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Windows 7 x64
jdk 1.7 and 1.8 installed
eclipse neon and eclipse mars

I have an existing project that runs fine in mars and am trying to import it into neon.  The existing project needs to run on jre 1.7

What I have done so far

I have changed the the execution environment in the run configuration to 1.7
I have changed the java compiler and targeted runtimes to 1.7 and installed jre is set to 1.7

The problem

In Mars in the Run Configuration/Plugins tab I click deselect all then 
re-select my plugin and then click Add Required plug-ins. Then I verify that everything is ok by clicking Validate Plugins which returns no problems where detected

In Neon with everything set to 1.7 as outlined above I get a bunch of problems Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE1.8 and Missing Constraint: Require-Capability: osgi.ee filter="(&(osgi.ee=JasvaSE)(Version=1.8))"

I would think that since I set everything to use the 1.7 framework then it should work just as it does when using Mars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Eclipse Neon plugins now require Java 8 and you will not be able to run them using Java 7.

If you really need to build something to run with Java 7 you will have to set up a target platform containing Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it

Comment: So if I'm in the situation that a plugin was developed with eclipse mars what I need to do is either continue developing under eclipse mars or if I am using eclipse neon, I need to set in the target the mars repository location?

Comment: @asdf If you want code that will still run on Eclipse Mars you need to use an Eclipse Mars target platform.

Comment: @greg-449 I am in situation where I already have a target file which points to a folder "marsrepository"( I assume that the reason why it was done like that was to offer portability on other eclipse versions as well)